# How to calculate the lowest possible altitude a satellite can orbit at due to aerodynamic heating if provided with a sufficient propulsion system?

Tags: reentry, low-earth-orbit, aerodynamics, thermal-control, very-low-earth-orbit

If a satellite is equipped with a propulsion system which is enough for compensating the local drag and maintaining the orbit, then aerodynamic heating would be the limiting factor for attaining the lowest possible altitude.

How can one calculate or at least estimate the limiting altitude for a given satellite? What major parameters or aspects of the satellite are required?

Comment: `+1` I've adjusted your question so that it's not closed for "needs detail or clarity". People will comment "It depends on the specific satellite" etc. I also adjusted your title to match the body of your question. While people can't give you an exact altitude until you give them an exact satellite (and then they still won't do it) written this way an answer can *explain how* this might be calculated and what factors you'll need to know. You can then ask a follow-up question. You are welcome to edit further or roll back. *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: 1. Are you sure atmospheric heating would be the limiting factor? Why?

Comment: 2. What you're describing sounds less like a satellite and more like an aircraft or cruise missile. What exactly do you mean by satellite?

Comment: @Dragongeek since the satellite is literally in orbit and LEO/VEO is specified in the tags, and the question is "how low" suggesting it starts in orbit higher, then it really does not sound like an aircraft.

Comment: Ermm... Are we back to "What would a Karman plane look like?"

Comment: The limiting factor is likely to be the propulsion system (and that's before you consider one can often dump heat into your propellant). ESA'a GOCE might be of interest

Comment: but as a very rough guide, if you calculate the horsepower of the engines you need to maintain orbit then that'll give, very roughly, the BTU/s you'll have to dissipate.

Comment: It sounds like the answer should be simple. Just find instantaneous drag acceleration and compute for required thrust. Altitude should be in that equation somewhere, so just evaluate for it. But, it's probably not that simple...

Comment: @BMFForMonica I took a stab at it with some liberal application of assumptions and approximations.

Comment: UHOH's answer is very cool.    But suppose you have a Zero-Point Module and thus infinite power available.  Then what's the thrust required to maintain orbital speed at, e.g.,  15 km altitude? (chosen so you won't hit any mountains).  Seems to me that's the question being asked here.   Or heck, do it for 1km along some orbital path that avoids mountain ranges (not technically possible, I fear).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that's mostly what my comment tried to describe. Orbital velocity at a given altitude can be known, so the problem is to solve for instantaneous drag acceleration at given altitude and then, with "spacecraft" mass, required thrust.

Comment: Atmospheric drag, decay, solar radiation is still very variable and we still don't have a deterministic time varying model (and we probably never will). Thus, there probably isn't a limit, but maybe you can checkout the Kármán line as a rough guide, as anything below it tends to have drag forces that prohibits most spaceflight with electric or ionic thrusters.

Comment: Discussion for this question describes on an altitude vs speed graph a "hypersonic breathing corridor" bounded above by airbreather limit and below by dynamic pressure limit. The dynamic pressure I understand, it would give rise to airframe stress. I don't know what the airbreather limit is. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44837/what-is-the-highest-operational-ceiling-for-an-air-breathing-jet-engine

Answer (score 5):

Following [@JCRM's lead](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41887/how-to-calculate-the-lowest-possible-altitude-a-satellite-can-orbit-at-due-to-ae#comment136848_41887): rocket horsepower questions to the rescue! See [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41854/12102) and [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20075/12102) for derivations and explanations.

### Power

If we assume that most of the kinetic energy of the air molecules striking the spacecraft is converted to heat (perhaps it's more like half or 2/3) then we can use the concept of "rocket power" which is really just the kinetic energy of the gas leaving a spacecraft calculated in the frame of the spacecraft.

$$\frac{dE}{dt} = P = \frac{v^2}{2}\frac{dm}{dt}$$

$\frac{dm}{dt}$ would be the mass of air encountered per unit time and is the density times the velocity time the area $\rho v A$.

If our drag shield were a plate of metal held "into the wind" thermally shielded and on insulating posts maintained at a temperature $T$ of 1000 Kelvin (about 730C) it could dissipate about $\sigma A T^4$ [by thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) assuming a shock wave hasn't formed in front that is so dense it starts radiating back and blocking radiation out. If that were the case then you'll need to absorb heat in front and re-radiate it out the back using a circulating liquid to transfer the heat, which sounds hard and also sounds like someone may have thought of this in the past.

$$P = \sigma A T^4 = \frac{v^2}{2}\frac{dm}{dt} = \frac{v^2}{2} \rho v A$$

$$P = \sigma A T^4 = \frac{1}{2} \rho v^3 A.$$

I'm leaving the drag coefficient equal to one, otherwise that is what [Wikipedia gets as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Power). Solving for density;

$$\rho = \frac{2 \sigma T^4}{v^3}.$$

The [Stefan Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) $\sigma$ is about 5.67E-08 W m<sup>-2</sup> K<sup>-4</sup>.

Put in 1000 K and 7800 m/s for example and we get roughly 2E-07 kg/m^3 or (also roughly) 2E-07 bar which puts it [roughly at](http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmos.htm) (found [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36618/12102)) the [Karman line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) at 100 km which makes [@JCRM's comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41887/how-to-calculate-the-lowest-possible-altitude-a-satellite-can-orbit-at-due-to-ae#comment136846_41887) about this being another "[Karman plane question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29721/12102)" either *eerily prescient or profoundly insightful!*

### What thrust is needed?

Since force is just power divided by velocity we remove one power of $v$ to get

$$F = \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 A.$$

At 2E-07 kg/m^2 that's 12 Newtons which is much bigger than you could easily do with solar-electric on a spacecraft with a 1 square meter cross section orbiting at 100 km. **You'll need a conventional thruster and so you'll run out of propellant quickly.**

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to calculate the thruster's horsepower ;-)

Comment: If thrust $$T = \frac{dm}{dt} v$$ then shouldn't the $$\frac{1}{2}$$ in the last formula  not be omitted ?

Comment: @Cornelisinspace that looks correct for [the drag force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Types_of_drag) doesn't it? Your equation is thrust force due to rocket exhaust with exhaust velocity $v$ and mass flow of $dm/dt$. That's not what my equation is about. I'm just saying that the aerodynamic drag is 12 Newtons on 1 square meter at 100 km.

Comment: I thought that because your last formula was a "derivative" of the first power formula you had to take the derivative of that formula. In your answer you don't say that the thrust formula is actually the drag force.

Comment: @Cornelisinspace I don't say it is a derivative, I just divide by velocity (power divided by velcity is force). Of course to remain in orbit thrust has to equal drag, no? It's not a coincidence that that is the result!

Comment: I meant *one* had to take the derivative of the velocity but i now see that 's not right because you assume that v is a constant. And  because  you compared  "gas leaving a spacecraft" with "air molecules striking the spacecraft" and used the concept of "rocket power" i wrongly thought the thrust equation should be used. Just an explanation !

Comment: @Cornelisinspace okay got it. I got the assumption that $v$ is a constant from the question: "...a propulsion system which is enough for compensating the local drag and maintaining the orbit..."

Comment: This is a nice answer!